# required is not working in the <md-select >

Tags: angularjs

can any one help how to do the md-select valitation in the angularjs project.

```
   <md-select  ng-model="address.AddrLabelId" md-on-close="addrLabelCheck(address.AddrLabelId)">    
        <md-option value="0">Choose Address Label</md-option>
        <md-option ng-repeat="addr in AddrLabelId | orderBy:'Name'" value="{{addr.Id}}">{{addr.Name}}</md-option>
  </md-select>
```

please give some example to better understand

Comment: Provide a codepen or Plunkr with your code ?

Have you gone through : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input

Answer (score -1):

U need to include `required` or `ng-required` as an attribute to the `<md-select>` tag